# Two masses on rope spinning around

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-velocity

> Two balls of the same mass $m$ are connected to each other with rope
>   of length $l$. One of the balls is also connected to the ceiling with
>   a rope of the same length $l$. The balls are spinning around the axis
>   which intersects the point of the connection of the rope in the
>   ceiling. As a result, they create angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with the
>   verticals. Masses of the two ropes can be neglected. What is the angular velocity of the system?

[image]

So I made a free body diagram:

[image]

And the equations are:

For the top ball:

$T_1 \cos \alpha = mg + T_2 \cos \beta\\
T_1 \sin \alpha - T_2 \sin \beta = m (l \sin \alpha) \omega^2$

For the bottom one:

$T_2 \cos \beta = mg\\
T_2 \sin \beta = m (l \sin \alpha + l \sin \beta ) \omega^2$

The process:

$T_1 \cos \alpha = 2mg\\
T_1 \sin \alpha = m (l \sin \alpha) \omega ^2+T_2 \sin \beta = m (l \sin \alpha) \omega ^2 + m(l \sin \alpha + l \sin \beta) \omega ^2=\omega ^2 m l(2\sin \alpha + \sin \beta)$

$2 mg \tan \alpha =\omega ^2 m l(2\sin \alpha + \sin \beta)$

And so:

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{2g \tan \alpha}{l(2\sin \alpha + \sin \beta)}}$$

However, according to the book the answer is:

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{g \tan \beta}{l(\sin \alpha + \sin \beta)}}$$

I'm quite stuck on that. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book answer seems correct (it can be obtained from the equations for the bottom body). I don't know how you obtained your result, but there is a possibility that it is also correct and actually coincides with the book answer, just because the equations for the top body provide an extra relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: I've plugged in some values for check, and the value of the expression that I got differs from the book's expression.

Comment: I've added my steps.

Comment: You cannot plug in arbitrary values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, as they are indeed related under the conditions of the problem. I found how to get your answer, and yes, it seems it's also correct, so it probably coincides with the book answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "conditions of the problem"? The only thing that I see this answer is dependent on is whether $\alpha$ smaller than $\beta$. I've assumed this is true. And even so, how can I obtain the book's answer?

Comment: As I said, you can get the book answer from the two equations for the bottom body (just eliminate $T_2$ from them).

Comment: I mean that, under the conditions of the problem, $\alpha$ defines $\beta$, and vice versa, so the two answers always coincide.

Comment: Gosh, I was blind, sorry. Indeed, I get book's answer. It is quite interesting that I do not actually need the other equations for obtaining the expression for angular velocity. Now I'm embarrassed that I even asked such a question :) Thank you.